# Doctrine CLI not working

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, silex

I started new project, based on Silex Micro Framework, but i stuck on doctrine cli extension. I used in some other projects, with Slim, or my own sample framework doctrine cli and there is work fine. 
Now, my **cli-config.php** is so simple:

```
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';

use App\Application;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\Console\Helper\ConnectionHelper;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Helper\EntityManagerHelper;

$app = Application::getInstance()->configure()->getApp();

$helperSet = new HelperSet(array(
    'db' => new ConnectionHelper($app['em']->getConnection()),
    'em' => new EntityManagerHelper($app['em'])
        ));
```

but not work very well, just return me doctrine.php contents

```
SRC_DIR="`pwd`"
cd "`dirname "$0"`"
cd '../doctrine/orm/bin'
BIN_TARGET="`pwd`/doctrine.php"
cd "$SRC_DIR"
"$BIN_TARGET" "$@"
```

I tried with this commands

```
php vendor/bin/doctrine.php orm

php vendor/doctrine/orm/bin/doctrine.php
```

and many other variations, none of these was helpful for me.
Maybe this is so little change, or typo bug ...

PS I debug everything in my cli-config.php file, $app['em'] return right instnace of EntityManager, everything look good (for me).

Comment: Just check vendor/bin/doctrine.php with my other project, and that are radically different. I Use "doctrine/orm": "2.5.1",

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know when ... but, with

```
php vendor/doctrine/orm/bin/doctrine.php orm
```

everything work fine. I post this as a answer, but i wanna know why

```
php vendor/bin/doctrine.php
```

not work o.O

Comment: It looks like the `vendor/bin/doctrine.php` accidentally has the `doctrine.bat` content instead of the PHP content.

The `vendor/doctrine/orm/bin/doctrine.php` works as it has valid PHP in it.